# Case statement in where clause oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In where clause i have two option 1) status = 'N' and type = '1'  and 2) status = 'Y' and type = '1'  based on parameter I need execute one option:

```
  where 
     case 
        when (carName = :P_PARAMETER) then  status = 'N' and type = '1'
        else status = 'Y' and type = '1'
     end
```

After execute get error any solution for solve this problem or other method?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the logic:

```
where type = '1'
  AND ((status = 'N' AND carName = :P_PARAMETER))
        OR status = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

The option `type = '1'` is common in both cases so you can leave it out of the CASE statement (also because it would be syntactically wrong to try to return 2 values from the CASE statement):

```
where 
  type = '1' 
  and
  status = case when carName = :P_PARAMETER then 'N' else 'Y' end
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `decode()` function :

```
 where type = '1'  -- common for all cases
   and status= decode(carName,:P_PARAMETER,'N','Y')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d6032d553d47c9a9a9c60608e283b332)</kbd>